# Activeadmin form - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin

How I can make this form in activeadmin?

```
<%= form_for(@album, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
.....

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :apellido %><br />
<%= f.text_field :apellido %>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <p>Hijos</p>
    <%= f.fields_for :hijos do |builder| %><br /><br />
    <%= builder.label :nombre, 'Nombre Hijo' %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :nombre %><br />
    <%= builder.label :apodo, 'Apodo Hijo' %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :apodo %><br />
    <%= builder.label :hijo_id, 'favorito' %>
    **<%= f.radio_button :hijo_id, builder.object.id %>**
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I need put the option of `hijo_id` inside the for of `:hijos`

Try with :

```
 f.input :avatar_item_id, :as => :boolean, :value =>  app_f.object.id
```

But not work.

Thanks

Comment: What are the relationships you have set up for Album and Hijo models?

Comment: Album = Padre

Album ->> nombre, apellido, hijo_id

Hijo ->> nombre, apodo

Answer (score 1):

This should work once you register the Album model as an ActiveAdmin resource:

```
  form :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
    f.inputs "Principal" do
      f.input :apellido
    end

    f.inputs "Hijos" do
      f.has_many :hijos do |h|
        h.input :nombre
        h.input :apodo
        h.input :favorito, :as => :check_box
      end
    end
    f.buttons
    end
```

If you want to mark a `child` as a favorite, you need a boolean `favorito` field in the `hijos` table, not a `hijo_id` field.

Comment: I want that father table save the favorites son (hijo)
if father table has the favorites just need a query. If son table save the favorites need other query for know who is the favorites and need made more validations for not save duplicates favorites in sons tables

Greetings

Comment: In that case the hijo_id must be outside the nested form, not inside. The hijo_id must be saved in the Father table

Comment: the 'favorite' field is part of the Fhater model but need collect the value of the Item 

Need something like this. (in front form works, but not in the admin)
 
f.input :favorito, :value => h.object.id